# Oracle Apex - Apex Office Print / Bind variable does not exist

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using Apex Office Print in order to export powerpoint templates.
However, I'm getting this error with several of my existing (and correctly calculated) bind variables:

''Bind variable does not exist''

Here's an example of my query:

```
select
  'file1' as "filename", 
  cursor(
    select
    :P58_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER as "EMPLOYEES",
    :P58_SALARY          as "SALARY"
    from dual
  ) as "data"
from dual
```

- I have these items on my ppt template set as {EMPLOYEES} and {SALARY}
- Page Items are exactly named like in the example ( :P58_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER / :P58_SALARY )

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the reason why, AOP doesn't like long bind variable names.
Had to shorten the name for them all in order for AOP to work.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found the answer yourself. How big are your bind names?
I believe you can have up to 30 characters as a bind variable.